# how work "expand cells containing lists into their own variables in pandas"

Tags: python, pandas, list

[Here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists/) show how expand cells containing lists into their own variables in pandas.
There is this solution too:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['tags']),axis=1)
```

But I don't understand how it work. Any one can explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means convert each value of column `tags` to `Series`, which are converted to `DataFrame` - it concat `Series` together. `axis=1` mean processes by rows, where each row is converted to Series, so need `x['tags']` for select `tags`.

Also is possible create custom function for better check each step:

```
def f(x):
    #each row is convert to Series
    print (x)
    #select row tags
    print (x['tags'])

    #convert list to Series
    return pd.Series(x['tags'])

tags = df.apply(f,axis=1)
print (tags)
```

If performance is important and larger DataFrame, better is use:

```
tags = pd.DataFrame(df['tags'].values.tolist())
print (tags)
       0     1      2
0  apple  pear  guava
1  truck   car  plane
2    cat   dog  mouse
```

**Performance**:

```
# create a dataset
raw_data = {'score': [1,2,3], 
        'tags': [['apple','pear','guava'],['truck','car','plane'],['cat','dog','mouse']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['score', 'tags'])

# view the dataset
#print (df)

#3000 rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [110]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['tags']),axis=1)
792 ms ± 27.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [111]: %timeit df['tags'].apply(pd.Series)
681 ms ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [112]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df['tags'].values.tolist())
715 µs ± 8.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

apply lets you pass all rows (axis=1) or columns (axis=0) of a DataFrame to a function that is given as a parameter to the apply-function. Basically you write

```
DataFrame.apply(function, axis)
```

where the function could be predifined like the numpy sum-function or you can declare a lambda expression.

In this case each row "x" of the DataFrame "df" is passed to the function "pd.Series(x['tags'])" as a Series object. For each row the value of the tags-column will be used to create a new Series object.

If you do this for all rows, you end up with a bunch of single Series objects, which are used at the end to create a new DataFrame.